# How create keystore for release and not on debug? flutter

Tags: android, google-play, flutter

I followed the steps for deployment for flutter using this website https://flutter.io/android-release/

And when i run flutter build apk i get this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file filepath/key.jks> not found for signing config 'release'.
```

what i'm i missing to make it so it will sign for release?

when i change the line `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` to `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug` in my build.gradle it works, but to need it to be sign for release

my build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

folder structure:

```
Project

-Android
|-- .gradle
|-- app
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       |-- java
|   |       |-- res
|   |       `-- AndroidManifest.xml
|   `-- build.gradle
|-- gradle
|   `-- wrapper
|-- gradle.properties
|-- gradlew
|-- local.properties
|-- proguard-rules.pro
|-- gradlew.bat
`-- key.properties
```

i left out files under wrapper, java, and res

key.properties

```
storePassword=<placeholder1>
keyPassword=<placeholder1>
keyAlias=key
storeFile=</Users/Conner/key.jks>
```

Comment: could you post your folder structure for your android project?

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Just take a picture of your folder structure? Where do you defined the keyAlias, ... vars?

Comment: I defined it in key.properties, folder structure in edit

Comment: did you put the full path on  " storeFile=<placeholder2> " ?

Comment: Im pretty positive that it is, under "users/myname/key.jks"... when i run "flutter build apk"when i put debug instead of release it works fine (see above question)

Comment: It should be the full path... Eg:  /home/users/yourname/yourkey.jks

Comment: On a mac the root is /Users i believe... i tried doing "home" and "macintosh HD", i guess there is something i missing there...

Comment: Open your Terminal and type: pwd

Comment: It is just "/" and that signifies the hardrive

Comment: Navigate to your key folder on terminal and type pwd

Comment: /Users/Myname/key.jks

Comment: Is it the same as your storeFile var? Without <>

Comment: it is the exact same

Comment: It's weird, are you sure there are no typo/case sensitive?

Comment: Could this be the problem..... the error has the root to my app directory too...." Keystore file /Users/myname/AndroidStudioProjects/ICISI/android/app/</Users/myname/key.jks> not found for signing config 'release'."

Comment: Update the question with your real storeFile var.

Comment: it is updated ..

Comment: Don't use  <    > chars remove those

Comment: Yup that was it, thank you so much for bearing with me.... the password also shouldn't use them either

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must remove the '<' chars, it's only as sample data.

```
storePassword=yourpasswordhere
keyPassword=yourkeypasswordhere
keyAlias=youralias
storeFile=/your/path/key.jks
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid conflicts place the **key.jks** file inside **android\app\key** folder and in key.properties file add

`storePassword=yourpasswordhere
 keyPassword=yourkeypasswordhere
 keyAlias=youralias
 storeFile=key/key.jks`

Comment: According to the documentation, kjs file should be kept somewhere safe, not public, and that should not be in you app folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio and if you want to place your key in any folder other than android than you have to use the following format for **storeFile** in your **key.properties** file:

```
storePassword=app_bar_demo_key
keyPassword=app_bar_demo_key
keyAlias=app_bar_demo_key
storeFile=E:\\Dharmik\\Flutter\\Demo\\Keystore\\your_key_name.jks
```

I have demonstrated my keypath but you have to use the path where your key is stored but your path should be separated using '**\\**'(double backslash) instead of **'\'**(single backslash) as I have shown above.
Using this method you can place your key in any location you want.