# Keystore file not set for signing config release: can't build apk

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build, apk, keystore

The application works perfectly but at the time of building the apk appears the message of the image.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilrrN.png)

Thanks.

Comment: did you added keystore file to sign the release build??

THis might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432885/how-create-keystore-for-release-and-not-on-debug-flutter

Comment: @GoVindh I searched where is the keystore file but didnt found, or I don't know how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57814308/13049288

You need to do this!

once you add keystore file you can build release apk

Comment: @GoVindh I dont have the "key.properties" should I create it inside the project?

Comment: yes you need create it!